# Magento: Remove Right Sidebar from Success Page

Tags: php, xml, magento

I'm trying to remove the right sidebar from the success page but right now I don't know how to do it.

Until now I've changed

*app/design/frontend/default/theme/layout/checkout.xml*
*app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml*

adding to them this code

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <label>One Page Checkout Success</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

I've cleared all the cache and still nothing changed, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you know the name of the sidebar block which you want to remove you can always do `<remove name="NAME_HERE" />`

Comment: Can I remove it ONLY in the success page? if so how can I do it?

Comment: I'm sure it should work like that if you wrap it in the `<checkout_onepage_success>` tags

Comment: By the handle as @Karl wrote. And please check this Q&A site, it should have this answered with bells and whistles: http://magento.stackexchange.com/ -. just FYI: The code you've posted so far does not show where you tried to remove it. So are you actually looking for the documentation where it's written down how it works?

Comment: Hi hakre, thank you for your reply. I've checked the magento.stack... but I didn't find it helpful with my problem and I didn't want to resurrect old posts. 

(Please, for whoever put the "-1" when you do it just tell me where I'm doing wrong so that I won't do it again later)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure your success page is coming using the same layout handle. For this add the below code on success page template and check the applied handles.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles());
echo '</pre>';
```

If you found `checkout_onepage_success` in the output array then perform the below steps.

Create `local.xml` file in your current theme layout and add the following code:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to change the root page template is create a local.xml inside your theme with the following:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_success>
        <update handle="page_one_column" />
    </checkout_onepage_success>
</layout>
```

An isolated setTemplate in root block does not update the template because it needs the additional actions that are in page.xml, like 1.

If you would like to go deeper and understand the reasons take a look the following code into Mage_Page_Helper_Layout

```
if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('root') &&
    !$this->getLayout()->getBlock('root')->getIsHandle()) {
        // If not applied handle
        $this->getLayout()
            ->getBlock('root')
            ->setTemplate($pageLayout->getTemplate());
}
```

Best regards